# How can I use Ultimate Guitar tabs for backing

Tags: midi, daw, homerecording

I would like to record a song with tabs I find in ultimate guitar. It export tabs as GP5, but no midi files.

I want to record my guitar playing, but use drums/bass automatically generated via DAW.

I have Garageband and Ableton Live. Do I need guitar pro? Can it record guitar? Or is there a way to make Garageband ot Ableton read GP5?

Comment: Do the GP5 files contain accompaniment information? Is there notes for drums and bass, or guitar only? Do you need the computer to generate backing tracks that go together with a given guitar tab?

Comment: There are notes for all. I need computer to generate audio for given notes for drums ans bass.

Answer (score 1):

According to the video "How to Import A Guitar Pro File into MuseScore" by Traveling Guitarist (below), you can just drag and drop a GP5 file into the MuseScore UI. This is demonstrated in the video.

From there, MuseScore allows for saving as a MIDI file. Just select `File -> Export...` and then choose MIDI from the selection of file types.